# How to connect to elasticsearch using java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7.3 version, I am very new to this, all i want is to connect to elasticsearch node, i have installed ealasticsearch in one of the google cloud instance now i want to connect to elasticsearch and create index, delete index using java, how can i achieve that, i used this code but its full of error

```
public class ElasticConnection {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

// on shutdown

client.close(); 
    }

}
```

tell what jar should i add or what should i do, please help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public RestHighLevelClient createESRestClient() {
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(esUserName, esPassword));

    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient
            .builder(new HttpHost(esRestclientHost, 9200, "http"));
    // Use this one if your ElasticSearch server is setup to use username & password authentication
    if (esAuthentication) {
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(h -> h.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
    }

    return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
}
```

You can use the following code to create your ElasticSearch connection. `RestHighLevelClient` is the new client which replaced `TransportClient`, I suggest that you use `RestHighLevelClient`.

For your reference this is listed in the ElasticSearch documentation guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.3/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html

Comment: yes my elasticsearch is password-protected, i used this code but `esUserName` says cannot find symbol, i know i am asking a dumb question, should i pass a string of user-name and password like "elastic" and "elastic" ?

Comment: yes the `esUserName` and `esPassword` are plain strings. Just pass the credentials you have configured in your ElasticSearch. Also the `esRestclientHost` is just the hostname of your ElasticSearch server.

Comment: You can ignore `esAuthentication` it was a simple boolean in my code to indicate as a switch whether i need to provide credentials or not. A switch between my Local Elastic instance vs. the Actual environment Elastic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the TransportClient - it is deprecated. use the high level rest client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.3/java-rest-high.html.

Also, note that the rest port is 9200, for when using the java high level rest client.

another option that you can use and worth mentioning is Jest: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest

Comment: i added some jar file and copy the given code but it says `cannot find symbol HttpHost` .

Comment: I suggest you read the full documentation of the library you use. Adding jars to your project and hoping it would work is optimistic. Start with a working example. You can look at tests to understand it as well

Comment: Happy to hear. Good luck